# Google Extantions Nodejs Get information (reading 'querySelector')

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use my google extensions on my websites so I write extension, Extension have button, when I press button I call this function: `scrapeEmailsFromPage` Extension work when I put some text. But I need to get mail address in this div class area:

```
 <div class="ContactView_data__+QQmF"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2040/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="currentColor" class="Icon_icon__rqEEN ContactView_solidIcon__v5Fuh" role="img" width="16px" height="16px" focusable="false"><title>E-mail address</title>
    <path d="M464 64c26.5 0 48 21.46 48 48 0 15.1-7.1 29.3-19.2 38.4L275.2 313.6a32.1 32.1 0 0 1-37.4 0L19.2 150.4C7.113 141.3 0 127.1 0 112c0-23.51 21.49-48 48-48h416zM217.6 339.2a63.9 63.9 0 0 0 76.8 0L512 176v208c0 33.3-28.7 64-64 64H64c-35.31 0-64-28.7-64-64V176l217.6 163.2z"></path></svg>
<a class="Normalize_normalize__5biS5 Link_root__FUNP5 Link_fontStyling__+NQdw ContactView_contactData__fQo58" href="mailto:hobik@gmail.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" role="link" target="_self" title="hobik@gmail.com" data-testid="EV_contactperson-email">hobik@gmail.com</a></div>
```

I'm trying to get this email address: hobik@gmail.com,

and I'm trying to this code:

```
function scrapeEmailsFromPage(){
    // const emailRegex = /[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}/gim;

    // Parse emails from HTML pf the page
    // let emails = document.body.innerHTML.match(emailRegex)
    // alert(emails)
    const divElement = document.querySelector('div.ContactView_data__+QQmF');
    console.log(divElement)
    const emailElement = divElement.querySelector('a.ContactView_contactData__fQo58');
    const email = emailElement.textContent;
    console.log(email);
    // chrome.runtime.sendMessage({emails})



}
```

But in the console I get this error:

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')
    at scrapeEmailsFromPage (<anonymous>:8:37)
    at <anonymous>:15:3
s
```

in this line

```
const emailElement = divElement.querySelector('a.ContactView_contactData__fQo58');
```

How can I get this mail address ? Can you help me.

This all code:

```
let scrapeEmails = document.getElementById('scrapeEmails');

//Handler to receive emails form content script

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender,sendResponse)=>{
    let emails = request.emails
    alert(emails)
})


scrapeEmails.addEventListener("click", async()=>{

    //Get current active tab
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow:true});
    // Execute script to parse emails on page
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        func: scrapeEmailsFromPage,
    })
})

//Function to scrape emails
function scrapeEmailsFromPage(){
    // const emailRegex = /[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}/gim;

    // Parse emails from HTML pf the page
    // let emails = document.body.innerHTML.match(emailRegex)
    // alert(emails)
    const divElement = document.querySelector('div.ContactView_data__+QQmF');
    console.log(divElement)
    const emailElement = divElement.querySelector('a.ContactView_contactData__fQo58');
    const email = emailElement.textContent;
    console.log(email);
    // chrome.runtime.sendMessage({emails})



}
```